# Streamwriter crashes when writing to existing file

Tags: c#, file, exception, streamwriter

Here is the code I have that writes to a couple of files:

```
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\TotalStock\data\points\" + stockName.ToUpper() + ".txt");

for(int i = 0; i < lines; i++)
{
   writer.WriteLine(lineData[i]);
   postGui.Send((object state) =>
    {
       progressBar2.PerformStep();
    }, null);
}

writer.Close();
```

When I delete the text files and run the code there is no issue, but then when I close the application and run it once more the program gives me the following error.  What is it that causes this error and what can I do to stop it?

Error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: The process cannot access the file 'C:\TotalStock\data\points\IBM.txt' because it is being used by another process

Comment: Obviously,that file you're trying to overwrite is opened in some kind of application and therefore it is "in use" and cannot be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the problem is that you open the file but do not close it when you exit the program. i see you are using `StreamWriter` to write the data to the file.
might by you get an exception and therefor does not close the file. when playing with files you should always do:

```
try
{
   // Your code with files
}
catch
{
}
finally
{
   writer.Close();
}
```

other reasons might be that you are using some other File/Stream/etc. please be sure that you close all the members that need to be closed before close the program.

please share all your code if you want us to check if you forgot something else

as Sayse Is saying another way to make sure you close your writers is a using statement:

```
using(StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\TotalStock\data\points\" + stockName.ToUpper() + ".txt");)
{
    // Your code of playing with files
}
```

Comment: Thats my point, its not also a valid way, imho its the only valid way and the only way you can be guarranteed that something will be disposed as you expect it to

Comment: @Sayse the finally way served me well for eons... i'll add the using way to my answer and we'll call truce, ok?

Answer (score 0):

As marc_s pointed out, the error occurs because the file you are trying to edit is opened by another application. If you are certain that you don't have the file opened in any other editor/viewer, the problem may the program itself.

If several instances of the same code run concurrently and require access to the same file, say in a multithread environement.

Does another component in your application read from the text file while you are trying to write to the file?
Does your application hang, and the second instance requires the same file?
Do you run the same tests each time?

Comment: Like I said, the issue here is that it only has this problem when the file already exists.  If I delete the file and then run the program there is no error

Comment: I ask about reading the file in your application, because that should be the only explanation, should be... Another thing, try to delete the document after you created it and the application is running.